# Patterns in a 3x3 grid

Tags: c++, depth-first-search

The goal is to find the different patterns available in a pattern lock of your average android home screen lock. For simplicity, I considered limiting my search space to a 3x3 grid. Some key points I inferred are mentioned below:

1. Based on the linearity of the hop, it can be classified as either a straight hop(with equal displacements along both axes) or a crooked hop (displacement along X axes + displacement along Y axes = 3).

   2. We can also take jumps of 2 units at a time, if the inter-mediate vertex has already been visited.

*Note : One thing I'd like to point out is that the purpose of using `patternsHelperPrime` to call `patternsHelper` is only to retain the original vector consisting of 1s for the next call in `patterns` function.*

Along the lines of DFS, I came up with the following code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void patternsHelper(vector<vector<int>> &matrix, int totalRows, int totalColumns, int row, int column, int &count, int depth)
{
    if (row < 0 || row >= totalRows)
        return;
    if (column < 0 || column >= totalColumns)
        return;

    if (matrix[row][column] == 1)
    {
        // we have to connect atleast 4 points
        if (depth == 3)
        {
            cout << "incrementing count to " << count + 1 << '\n';
            count++;
        }

        matrix[row][column] = 0;
        // check for immediate links

        // straight-up gangsta
        patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row, column + 1, count, depth + 1);
        patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row, column - 1, count, depth + 1);
        patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row + 1, column, count, depth + 1);
        patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row - 1, column, count, depth + 1);

        // dragon valley
        patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row + 1, column + 1, count, depth + 1);
        patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row - 1, column - 1, count, depth + 1);
        patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row + 1, column - 1, count, depth + 1);
        patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row - 1, column + 1, count, depth + 1);

        // crooked one-two links
        patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row - 2, column + 1, count, depth + 1);
        patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row - 2, column - 1, count, depth + 1);
        patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row - 1, column + 2, count, depth + 1);
        patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row - 1, column - 2, count, depth + 1);

        patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row + 1, column + 2, count, depth + 1);
        patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row + 1, column - 2, count, depth + 1);
        patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row + 2, column + 1, count, depth + 1);
        patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row + 2, column - 1, count, depth + 1);

        // straight-up bhopping links
        if (matrix[row][column + 1] == 0)
            patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row, column + 2, count, depth + 1);
        if (matrix[row][column - 1] == 0)
            patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row, column - 2, count, depth + 1);
        if (matrix[row + 1][column] == 0)
            patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row + 2, column, count, depth + 1);
        if (matrix[row - 1][column] == 0)
            patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row - 2, column, count, depth + 1);

        if (matrix[row + 1][column + 1] == 0)
            patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row + 2, column + 2, count, depth + 1);
        if (matrix[row - 1][column - 1] == 0)
            patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row - 2, column - 2, count, depth + 1);
        if (matrix[row + 1][column - 1] == 0)
            patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row + 2, column - 2, count, depth + 1);
        if (matrix[row - 1][column + 1] == 0)
            patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row - 2, column + 2, count, depth + 1);
    }
}

void patternsHelperPrime(vector<vector<int>> matrix, int totalRows, int totalColumns, int row, int column, int &count, int depth)
{
    patternsHelper(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, row, column, count, 0);
}

int patterns(vector<vector<int>> matrix)
{
    int result = 0;
    int totalRows = matrix.size();
    int totalColumns = matrix[0].size();

    for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < totalColumns; j++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            patternsHelperPrime(matrix, totalRows, totalColumns, i, j, count, 0);
            result += count;
        }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> matrix = {
        {1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1}};

    cout << patterns(matrix) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: What is your question?